# Wordpress API: Add super user (site admin)

Tags: php, wordpress

I can add an administrator like this:

```
$password = wp_generate_password();
$userData = array(
    'user_pass'     => $password,
    'user_login'    => $email,
    'user_nicename' => sanitize_title($name),
    'user_email'    => $email,
    'display_name'  => $name,
    'role'      => 'administrator'
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userData);
```

That works fine, but how do I add a super user? What is the role name?

I tried 'role' => 'super user', 'super_user', 'superuser', ... but nothing works.

Comment: Isn't administrator the highest level within WordPress? -- EDIT - Multisite super user - apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are basically correct, but it is better to use built-in functions from WordPress whenever possible. The function you are looking for is [`grant_super_admin()`](http://wpseek.com/grant_super_admin/).

Based on your example code:

```
$password = wp_generate_password();
$userData = array(
    'user_pass'     => $password,
    'user_login'    => $email,
    'user_nicename' => sanitize_title($name),
    'user_email'    => $email,
    'display_name'  => $name,
    'role'          => 'administrator'
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userData);

// Make the user a super admin.
grant_super_admin( $user_id );
```

Comment: I did not test this but it looks better than [my version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10811591/956397) with `add_user_to_blog()` and `update_site_option('site_admins', ..)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick flick through the WordPress code and I believe the option you are looking for is actually "site_admin"

Answer (score 1):

There is no such role.

The super admins are stored as site options as you can see in the function `get_super_admins`. 
In `is_super_admin` it is checked whether the user's login is in the array returned by the former function.

Usually this is only the user with the login name admin. What you need to to is

```
$admins = get_super_admins();
$admins[] = 'your_user_login@example.com';
update_site_option('site_admins', $admins);
```

Comment: This did not really work. I think I need to add the user as admin for each blog...

Comment: Did you try debugging into the `is_super_admin` function to see why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's working:

1) Set user role to "site_admin"

2) Add user as administrator for every blog

```
$blogs = get_blog_list(0, 'all');
foreach ($blogs as $blog)
{
    add_user_to_blog($blog['blog_id'], $user_id, 'administrator');
}
```

3) [As Alex said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598578/956397), add to site_admins:

```
$admins = get_super_admins();
if (!in_array($email, $admins))
{
    $admins[] = $email;
    update_site_option('site_admins', $admins);
}
```